# Does an equivalent of marks in vim exist for navigating notebooks quickly?

Tags: notebooks, front-end

Is it possible in the Mathematica front-end to associate a keyboard shortcut with a cursor location in the notebook (kind of like marks in vim) so that one can return to them quickly later?

(Just wondering if this functionality exists in some easy-to-use form already or if it would be necessary to build something from scratch using presumably the front-end tokens.)

Comment: Thanks for the link ... I was envisioning a mark-setting mechanism that would be more immediate and more temporary in nature.  For example, if I'm moving between three places in the notebook I'd like to be able to have the cursor bounce between those three locations with just a keystroke or two.  Adding, searching, and then deleting comments feels somewhat like a hack and is certainly less convenient than I would prefer but might be worth introducing into my workflow if nothing better exists.

Comment: Looking at the code in the link a little more carefully it appears not too difficult to modify it to a) create bookmarks that are invisible or at least less visually intrusive and b) create keyboard shortcuts to delete bookmarks.